# Eclipse: Create IEditorPart by ID

Tags: eclipse-plugin

How do I create an IEditorPart in an eclipse plugin by ID?

Note, I know I can do:

```
    IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
    page.openEditor(
                input,
                "the-editor-id);
```

However, that's not what I want. I want to create an IEditorPart so that I can embed it into a multi page editor. I don't have direct access to the editor class, so I can't instantiate one directly with "new".

Thanks.

Comment: I can't see any way to do this. All the existing multi-page editors just `new` the editor they want to use.

Comment: If you don't have direct access to the editor class, this *really* sounds like something they don't want you to do.

Comment: @nitind In fact this is code we control, but for various practical reasons can't instantiate directly. It's an optional dependency.. Besides, I can open an editor by ID quite easily, just not create the IEditorPart directly. Don't see why the latter should be any different to the former really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, this is what I did.
Note, it uses Non-API. There doesn't seem to be a mechanism of doing it using official API:

```
    EditorDescriptor d = (EditorDescriptor)PlatformUI
            .getWorkbench()
            .getEditorRegistry()
            .findEditor("my.editor.id");
    IEditorPart editor = d.createEditor();
```

The EditorDescriptor class and the createEditor method are non-api. The IEditorDescriptor interface doesn't declare the createrEditor method.